# Inexplicable behaviour in spritekit physics game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am working on a little project that is a game that scrolls up instead of left. So , I have collision detection on my sprite and the floor to determine when the character can jump and to avoid double / infinite jumping. However when my tilemap is scrolling somethinng weird is occuring. The "koala" sprite seems to somehow "bounce" of the tilemap and I dont think it is a property of the physics engine as if i turn off scrolling jumping is just fine. But when scrolling is on I get these little millimeter bounces occuring. I know an image doesnt quite capture it but I added my Nslog and this is the collision code. Restitution is set to zero on the floor the player and when  i turn off scrolling and just jump...no bouncing occurs

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (collision == (PCWallCategory|PCPlayerCategory)) {

    NSLog(@"Can jummp");
    onGround=YES;
  }else if (collision == (PCWinCategory|PCPlayerCategory)) {

    NSLog(@"You win");

    //onGround=YES;
  }
}

- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  // 1
  SKPhysicsBody *other = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PCPlayerCategory ?
                          contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA);
  if (other.categoryBitMask & _player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask) {
    // 3
    NSLog(@"dont jumps");
    onGround=NO;
}
}
```

[image]

Art work and original tutorial from 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/62049/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1

Comment: May I see the code that updates your viewpoint? Also, are you using tmx maps?

Comment: @Roecrew Well, Its actually "solved" thou dont understand how. You see that while picture running vertically on the side? its a SKSpriteNode which i added the tilemap as a child of so it could scroll since I dont know how to scroll the tilemap. (so i scroll that background and the tilemap scrolls). I added the koala as a child of that image and it doesnt spam collision again.(thou if i look really really hard it still seems to be doing a little bump not sure i like that fix but its the best i got)  Also it is a tmxtilemap and when you say update my viewpoint you mean my update method?

Comment: I mean the statements that update the center of view.

Comment: @Roecrew I dont believe i have any code doing that

Comment: There has to be, how else would your koala not be moving off screen?

Comment: @Roecrew The center doesnt focus on the Koala, thats not my intention. the game keeps scrolling an the koala can be "left" behind. when he is "left" behind that will be my lose logic. so he has to keep up with the screen . Quote unquote